# input 3d data to lstm

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm

I want to fit model on 3D data.

```
Y = pd.get_dummies(tag_data['tag']).values
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 42)
print(X_train.shape,Y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape,Y_test.shape)
batch_size = 32
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs = 10, batch_size=batch_size, verbose = 2)
```

```
(7, 273, 10) (7, 2)
(2, 273, 10) (2, 2)

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_2_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (7, 273, 10)
```

Comment: Can we see your model?

Comment: Not sure much but [This might help](https://medium.com/@shivajbd/understanding-input-and-output-shape-in-lstm-keras-c501ee95c65e)

Comment: 10 features in a 273-step sequence? Do you really need an embedding for the 10 features? Are they integers?